# jaxws-spring maven dependency is for what purpose

Tags: spring, maven

I have the following maven dependecy in my project.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
   <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Question:

- Is this [Spring Webservices](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-services) project?
- If not what this dependency is for?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [project](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/) combining JAX-WS and Spring.  Basically it gives you the wss namespace that you might be using in your application context to expose JAX-WS providers as web services.  It isn't mandatory but it can be a convenience as it allows you to easily have dependency injection in your servlets although there are other ways to get this.  Unfortunately, the last time I was using it I noticed that it was depending on some pretty old spring libraries (pre 3.x) and didn't seem to be updated in some time.